# Linux-Compatible Touchscreen Monitors (Non-Capacitive)

Tags: linux, monitors, touchscreen

I need to find a touchscreen monitor, preferably 24" or close to that, that is not a capacitive touchscreen (preferably resistive or optical), and is Linux-compatible.

I've had extremely bad luck finding anything along these lines and am wondering if I'll find anything. Most of the monitors I've been able to find by ViewSonic (TD2220 and TD2421) specify that they're Windows 7/8/10 only, but I've found a handful of reviews and Google results stating that basic touch functionality works in Linux.

I know that touchscreens aren't hot on the market, so I'm not surprised that the results are limited, but I'm a little disappointed that there are so few that work with Linux.